# stropts.h install for Ubuntu 20.01

Tags: 20.04, linux-headers, posix-compliant

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and am trying to compile my pintOS project and it says stropts.h not found and I have researched a bit that it only works on Ubuntu 18.04. Someone share a way to compile my project by getting stropts.h file.

I've already tried:

apt-get
libc6-dev
build-essentials

Comment: Check search results [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=stropts.h) for *focal* and then for *bionic*.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but the list of what you tried is unclear. In what way did you try "apt-get" etc? Also the package name is `build-essential`