# stropts.h missing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: development

I am having a problem in Xubuntu 20.04 (focal). I am trying to compile a scientific package (FreeUSP.org) and the compilation fails with:

```
chd_stat.c:10:10: fatal error: stropts.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <stropts.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have a computer with 18.04 (bionic) installed and the file is present in libc6-dev package. In 20.04 (focal) it does not list libc6-dev package as a source for this file:

```
$ apt-file search stropts.h
frama-c-base: /usr/share/frama-c/libc/stropts.h
libace-dev: /usr/include/ace/OS_NS_stropts.h
libace-dev: /usr/include/ace/os_include/os_stropts.h
libzfslinux-dev: /usr/include/libspl/stropts.h
libzfslinux-dev: /usr/include/libspl/sys/stropts.h
manpages-posix-dev: /usr/share/man/man7/stropts.h.7posix.gz
musl-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl/stropts.h
musl-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-musl/sys/stropts.h
python-pycparser: /usr/share/python-pycparser/fake_libc_include/stropts.h
python3-pycparser: /usr/share/python3-pycparser/fake_libc_include/stropts.h
```

This seems to be the same reported at [stropts.h install for Ubuntu 20.01](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237091/stropts-h-install-for-ubuntu-20-01/1285060#1285060).

Should a bug be reported to Ubuntu? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Please provide details about the compilation. From where have you downloaded source code? Which compiler do you use? What is the date of used source code?

Comment: As stated in the original text, it was downloaded from FreeUSP.org.  This is a very old software package that started the development about 40 years ago.   It is pretty much frozen in the last five or so years.

The compiler used is the set provided by:
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

The software was written using C and Fortran.


It used to build without problem until Xubuntu 18.04.

The problem now, as far as I could progress in compilation, is the missing header file 'stropts.h' that was present in the package libc6-dev at least until Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Have this been resolved for you? I now found that `ipmitool` fails to build on Ubuntu 20.04 with the same reason, except that it wants to `#include <sys/stropts.h>` which is also not found.

Comment: No, unfortunetely it was not.  :(

I learned at the time that Ubuntu had deprecated and purged some of the oldest development support and I found no alternatives.

Possibly it will be necessary to go through those old software and update them in someway. :/